# Overwrite or appending a collection using pyspark is deleting all indexes

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is the code that is being used

#### case 1

```py
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option(
    "uri", input_uri
).save()
```

#### case 2

```py
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("overwrite").option(
    "uri", input_uri
).save()
```

In both the scenarios the index at the mongo collection is dropped and it is causing issues at our end.
Is there a way we can avoid this at spark end?

Comment: Update:
The indexes are not deleted when we run in append mode