# create index in mongodb using apache spark scala with databricks

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a little question about connection in mongo using apache spark.

I have a simple dataframe like this:

| documentNumber | missions | createdDate | modifiedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | [{M1, ASSIGNED, 2022-10-20}, {M8, ASSIGNED, 2022-10-20}, {M9, ASSIGNED, 2022-10-20}] | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-20 |
| 12345676 | [{M2, ASSIGNED, 2022-10-20}] | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-20 |

And I used this code to insert in mongodb:

```
processedMissions
.write
.format("mongo")
.option("uri", mongoDbUri)
.option("collection", "missions")
.option("spark.mongodb.idFieldList","documentNumber")
.mode("overwrite")
.save()
```

but when I saw index in mongodb, I only saw the default index (_id), but in [this documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/write/), that way is the right option.

What is wrong?

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Which documentation are you referring to?

Both [this question](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001GHVgICAX/whats-the-difference-between-modeappend-and-modeoverwrite-on-my-delta-table) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969858/overwrite-or-appending-a-collection-using-pyspark-is-deleting-all-indexes#comment123695070_69969858) suggest that the `"overwrite"` mode will 'replace all of the data'. This probably implies that it drops and/or recreates the collection. New collections will only have the `_id` index by default.

Does using `.mode("append")` preserve the indexes as you are expecting?

If you do wish to remove all of the data but keep the existing indexes, you may need to take an alternative approach. That could be having some earlier code drop and recreate the collection (with relevant indexes) prior to using `"append"` to write the data.

Comment: sorry, this documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/write/ , I need to create an index of documentNumber.

Comment: I think for the most part _creating_ the index and _maintaining_ the index when using the Spark connector to write to MongoDB are two different concepts. Consider using the shell to create the index as outlined [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/), eg `db.collection.createIndex({documentNumber:1})`, and then changing your code to use the `append` mode (eg `.mode("append")`) so that the writes don't drop the collection along with the index.

Comment: well, I know about creating indexes using shell or a clean mongo connection with scala, but I wish create this index using apache spark.

Comment: I'm not sure the spark connector provides that functionality directly? Not immediately seeing anything in the docs, are you? That connector is mostly about moving data between systems rather than managing the collections as far as I can tell